# How to store output of a sql statement in a variable in C SHELL?

Tags: shell, unix, csh

How to store output of a sql in a variable in C SHELL?

set VAR =`sqlplus <<EOF
SELECT * FROM DB;
EXIT;
EOF`

I used above code but it is showing "Variable syntax"

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus <<EOF > /tmp/file
SELECT * FROM DB;
EXIT;
EOF

set VAR=`cat /tmp/file`
```

This may be some what equivalent to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR=$(sqlplus <<EOF
SELECT * FROM DB;
EXIT;
EOF
)

echo $var
```